# Refactoring Switch-Statement

Tags: swift, switch-statement, refactoring, global-variables

Is there a way to refactor this function in a way that I repeat my self as little as possible?

I have four ViewControllers which each hold a variable `eventData` which is a custom Object.

I thought about making `eventData` a global Variable. Are there any drawbacks doing so?

This is the code I am using right now:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    navigationItem.title = nil

    let segues = UIStoryboardSegue.Segue.self

    switch segue.identifier! {

    case segues.EventOverviewToGuestList.rawValue:

        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! GuestListVC

        destinationVC.eventData = eventData


    case segues.EventOverviewToAnalytics.rawValue:

        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! AnalyticsVC

        destinationVC.eventData = eventData


    case segues.EventOverviewToMessaging.rawValue:

        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! MessagingVC

        destinationVC.eventData = eventData


    case segues.EventOverviewToInformation.rawValue:

        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! InformationVC

        destinationVC.eventData = eventData

    default: break

    }

}
```

`segues` is a `enum`:

```
extension UIStoryboardSegue {

    enum Segue : String
    {

        case EventListToEventOverview
        case EventOverviewToGuestList
        case EventOverviewToAnalytics
        case EventOverviewToMessaging
        case EventOverviewToInformation

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have a base class that has this eventData member. Let us say-

```
class BaseViewController : UIViewController{
    var eventData : SomeCustomClass?
}
```

And derive all your view controllers that need the events data from it.

```
class InformationVC : BaseViewController{
}

class AnalyticsVC : BaseViewController{
}

class GuestListVC:BaseViewController{
}
```

Now your cases can be combined:

```
switch segue.identifier! {

  case segues.EventOverviewToGuestList,
     segues.EventOverviewToAnalytics,
    segues.EventOverviewToMessaging,
     segues.EventOverviewToInformation:

  let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! BaseViewController
  destinationVC.eventData = eventData

  default: break

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an EventDataProtocol on the ViewControllers that you need to set the eventData. Any view controller that uses the EventDataProtocol will always have the eventData set by the Segue. For example:

```
protocol EventDataProtocol {
    var eventData: Int? { get set } //Change to your actual type
}

class EventData: UIViewController, EventDataProtocol {
    var eventData: Int?
}
```

And then in your prepareForSegue method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender)

    if var eventDataVC = segue.destinationViewController as? EventDataProtocol {
        eventDataVC.eventData = 5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
struct EventData {}
```

define the following protocol

```
protocol Module0 { var eventData: EventData? { get set } }
```

and conform to it your view controllers

```
class GuestListVC: UIViewController, Module0 { var eventData: EventData? }
class AnalyticsVC: UIViewController, Module0 { var eventData: EventData? }
class MessagingVC: UIViewController, Module0 { var eventData: EventData? }
class InformationVC: UIViewController, Module0 { var eventData: EventData? }
```

Add a property to your enum

```
extension UIStoryboardSegue {

    enum Segue: String {
        case EventListToEventOverview
        case EventOverviewToGuestList
        case EventOverviewToAnalytics
        case EventOverviewToMessaging
        case EventOverviewToInformation

        static var allRawValues: [String] {
            return
                [
                    Segue.EventListToEventOverview.rawValue,
                    Segue.EventOverviewToGuestList.rawValue,
                    Segue.EventOverviewToAnalytics.rawValue,
                    Segue.EventOverviewToMessaging.rawValue,
                    Segue.EventOverviewToInformation.rawValue
            ]
        }
    }

}
```

Now it's pretty straightforward

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var eventData = EventData()
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        navigationItem.title = nil

        if var destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? protocol<Module0> where UIStoryboardSegue.Segue.allRawValues.contains(segue.identifier!) {
            destinationVC.eventData = eventData
        }
    }
}
```